# Wine update error

Tags: upgrade, updates, wine

[image]

I have this upgrade error pop up that comes up every so often.  I don't know what to do. The run action button doesn't work. When I click it, window to enter admin password pops up for half a second and disappears.  What's even more weird, I don't know why my system wants to download this Wine stuff.  I purged Wine from my Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you completely deleted? There may still be a wine PPA active...

Comment: I didn't see a Wine PPA in software sources

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to uninstall completely by executing:

```
sudo apt-get purge wine 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get install -f 
rm -r ~/.wine 
rm -r ~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programms 
rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/wine*
```

and then wine is *banished* from your system...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **:-)** I edited *and* upvoted.  Great first answer! (though the OP did not say anything about re-installing wine, so I removed that.

Comment: I don't think that uninstalling wine alone will fix this. I believe it's due to the files in `/usr/share/package-data-downloads/`. see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Specs/UpdateNotifierPackageDataDownloader

Answer (score -1):

If you do want to keep wine and only want to stop this message from popping up, try:

```
rm -f /usr/share/package-data-downloads/wine-browser-installer
rm -f /usr/share/package-data-downloads/wine-silverlight5.1-installer
```